# How to make a grid in html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a square grid that's n by n. at the moment I'm just doing it in js with translate but I'd like to have a way to have the grid contained within another element and scale as that element scales so it can be responsive. Ideally I'd like a solution that will allow me to remove set sizes for the grid squares and have them instead auto-adjust to fit the container. This is the code I have right now but it's obviously not a good solution:

```
 let n = 6;
  for(let i=0;i<(n*n);i++){
    let k = document.createElement("div");
    k.className += "tile";
    k.style.transform = "translate("+(100*(i%n)).toString()+"%, "+(100*Math.floor(i/n)).toString()+"%)";
    document.getElementById("tiles").appendChild(k);
  }
```

and this is the css:

```
.tile{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("Tiles/tile_01.png");
}
.tile:hover {
  opacity: 0.85;
}
```

Comment: look at CSS-grid,flexbox, inline-block, etc

Comment: Depending on what you need it for, you can also use `<table>`

Comment: I havent been able to get CSS-grid to work and with inlineblock and flexbox I'm not sure how to keep it layed out as a square and make sure each grid space is a square.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: replace positon:absolute with display:inline-block and remove all the transform

Comment: Temani, how do i ensure its a square then? wont it just wrap when it needs to rather than wrapping into a square? also the cells wouldnt resize to fit the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got it working by creating n row flexboxes nested in a column flexbox